Can I use an Enlarger for scanning negatives?
I was doing some reading about how to properly scan my negative films with my digital camera. I came a cross this wonderful post about how to create your own ICC profiles for your films, the catch is that you need very narrow bandwidths of light. I was wondering, if I could avoid buying a triband filter (which is like 1000 bucks) and use an enlarger head that has a magenta, yellow and cyan adjustment. Would this work? In my mind it does exactly what a power adjustable narrow band LED would do (of course I don´t know if the quality of filters in the enlarger are at all ok) and it is also made for color films. If anyone knows something about this or even has experience please let me know

Optically, flatbed scanners tend to suffer from vignetting when a lens is used to project an image on them. Essentially the pixels already have lenses on them and light coming in at an angle gets cut off some.  You might be able to use a fresnel to correct this like the screen on an SLR.  Many people have built cameras this way so it should be possible to find info on past projects if you can get past Google's recency bias.

Thank you for your response! I'm not sure I understood what you mean though, or there has been some misunderstanding. My "plan" isn't to use a flatbed scanner, but to simply harvest the light source from an enlarger and use it to illuminate my negatives to then "scan" with my slr. So just take a picture of the illuminated negative. But your input is greatly appreciated, and if what you said does relate to slr scanning please help me understand it :)

@jocka Welcome to Stack Exchange!  it might be good to add that information back into your question post as well - future readers may not read all comments, and that's an important part of the question to which you seek a definitive answer. Thanks!

You should be able to do this. It's a lot like transferring film reels to VHS.
It would require darkness and probably some parallax correction because only one thing can be directly in front of the image.  It would also require a good projection surface you could keep clean, like maybe a piece of a projection screen.
If you worked out back-projection you could solve the parallax problems and have effectively built a reverse slide printer.
Most people just use a good macro for this so there's only one lens.
